# Apache 500 Error AllowOverride All

Tags: apache2

If I enable AllowOverride for /var/www, I get an 500 Internal Server Error. The .htaccess File is located in /var/www/html. I have already enabled a2enmod rewrite.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart apache2 service, and check for any error message. If there is any, provide them in the  question, please.